# Serving blade file against html request using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a url as :  **http://abcd.com/product/home.html** and i want to serve a blade file against this request because that blade will have dynamic content.

I am using nginx to redirect this request to php server:

```
location /product/ 
{
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
      proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
      access_log on;
}
```

I have tried solutions like :

```
Route::get('/product/home.html', function() { return View::m/ake('product.camsproduct'); } );
```

But its giving error like :

[404]: (null) /product/home.html - No such file or directory

Comment: not sure what `View::make()` does can you check routes using `php artisan route:list`

Comment: You will see all the routes you created in web and api, maybe broadcasting too.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth thats not a concern, even if i am trying to print a log its just not working. The problem is that its not being triggered i guess

Comment: what is not a concern? did you check your route lists? 404 means the route is not available.

Comment: nginx 404 or laravel 404?

Comment: @lagbox laravel 404

Comment: +--------+----------+---------------------+------+-----------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                 | Name | Action    | Middleware |
+--------+----------+---------------------+------+-----------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | product/home.html   |      | Closure   | web        |
+--------+----------+---------------------+------+-----------+------------+  this is the result of that command @Mr.Kenneth

Comment: "No such file or directory" sounds like a webserver 404, not Laravel ... Laravel's default 404 page just says `404 | NOT FOUND`

Comment: @lagbox whats the solution then for this ??

Comment: why do you need to pass this off to another server? can you not have nginx pass fastcgi to php-fpm?

Comment: i am not aware of PHP-fpm can you please refer some useful document

Comment: I guess it's more related to webserver/nginx than PHP/Laravel, consider editing your tags.

Comment: I just noticed too, you dont typically use xxx.html at the end of your route when using Laravel. /product is enough for this. Instead of using nginx (if you are still in localhost/development) run `php artisan serve` and see the route

Comment: if i am not using any extension then this error is coming :--     [404]: GET /product/home.html - No such file or directory